# C++ File is not reading correctly... pointers?

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream

File is not reading correctly, it displays this...

[Here is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPhha.png)

The file is created and is in the same directory as the .cpp file but it won't open. View file extensions is on (in windows explorer) so that's not the problem...  Why is it not reading correctly?

I thought adding "ifstream inputFile;" in the scope of the functions would help but since it is declared globally then it shouldnt have to be. The file is spelled exactly how it is supposed to be since I know it is case sensitive.

This is just a piece of my code

full code
https://hastebin.com/pomahoyefi.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
char getUserChoice();
int calcNumber();
double calcSum();
double calcAvg();
ifstream inputFile;
int main()
{
ifstream inputFile;
char choice;
int num;
double sum;
double average;
do
{
    choice = getUserChoice();
    if (choice == 'a')
    {
        num = calcNumber();
        cout << "Number of scores is " << num << endl;
    }
    if (choice == 'b')
    {
        sum = calcSum();
        cout << "Sum of scores is " << sum << endl;
    }
    if (choice == 'c')
    {
        average = calcAvg();
        cout << "Average of scores is " << average << endl;
    }
}
while(choice == 'a' || choice == 'b' || choice == 'c');
return 0;
}
char getUserChoice()
{
char choice;
do
{
    cout << "Make your choice" << endl;
    cout << "================" << endl;
    cout << "a) Calculate the number of scores in the   le" << endl;
    cout << "b) Calculate the sum of all the scores in the  le" << endl;
    cout << "c) Calculate the average of all scores in the  le" << endl;
    cout << "d) Quit" << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    if (!(choice == 'a' || choice == 'b' || choice =='c' || choice =='d'))
    {
        cout << "Invalid input" << endl;
    }
}
while(!(choice == 'a' || choice == 'b' || choice =='c' || choice =='d'));
return choice;
}
int calcNumber()
{
ifstream inputFile;
double number;
int total = 0;
inputFile.open("studentData.txt");
if(! inputFile)
{
    exit(0);
}
else
{
    while (inputFile >> number)
    {
        ++total;
    }
    inputFile.close();
}
return total;
}
```

Comment: Where is your executable? Since your path is relative, your working directory for the executable needs to have that file (and that's not necessarily the same as the same location as the .cpp file). You can verify this by trying to open the .cpp file from that directory (it should fail). The simple solution is to find where the executable is and copy the input file to that same directory. The more correct solution may be to be more explicit in your path handling (though be careful not to hard code the full path in the assignment you turn in since your professor is likely to not have the same).

Comment: Post your file content (at least some initial lines).
How do you know it fails to open?

Comment: File is opened successfully, otherwise, a program would be ended with `exit(0)`

Comment: Please post the contents of studentData.txt. I am pretty sure this file does not only contain numbers. I think there is a string in the beginning of the file and that is why `(inputFile >> number)` returns false (because the fail bit was set). You should also NEVER use such an expression. `inputFile >> number` returns an `istream&` not a `bool`. Try it with `((inputFile >> number).good())`. You should also consider doing this with `!inputFile`

Comment: Also: pay attention to your compiler's warnings and tidy your code up. E.g. you have 3 different `ifstream inputFile` declarations, only 1 is used.